# Why do I never receive the displayed price for an item?

Tags: starfield

Sometimes I find a "high value" item like a weapon or a helmet and I see a value like 10'000.

Later, if I try to sell this item at a space port kiosk or a even a specific dealer, I can never sell this item for such a price. I only get about 10%.

What could be the reason for this difference between the displayed value in my inventory and the "street price"?

Comment: This has been the case for most if not all Bethesda RPGs. Usually there is some sort of "barter" skill you can upgrade to get better prices on goods you buy and sell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I hinted to in my comment, this is typically how it has always worked for Bethesda games (one [redditor](https://www.reddit.com/r/Starfield/comments/166veqn/comment/jym5ibw/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) shares the same thought!)

There is a [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Starfield/comments/1670ham/selling_price_inventory_vs_vendor/) that says its just a "value" and not a price:

> That’s a value not a sale price. Vendors are like pawn shops. They never give you full value. There are skills to increase what vendors will pay.

This [same post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Starfield/comments/1670ham/comment/jymzesp/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) also claims that selling items to different vendors may change the price they purchase it for:

> I've seen different prices in different stores in new Atlantis but I haven't tested the same store in different cities yet

The [Commerce Perk](https://starfield.fandom.com/wiki/Commerce) allows you to eventually get up to 25% more credits when selling an item, as well as paying 20% less when you buy an item from a vendor.

Comment: Some characters will pay extra prices for certain goods too. For example, Vladimir will pay more a for surveys than a vendor will.

Comment: @Mufasa Who is "Vladimir"?

Comment: @TylerH https://screenrant.com/starfield-credits-survey-data-vladimir-eye/ looks like survey data he buys for more than normal vendors

Comment: @TimmyJim OK, so the Vladimir in The Eye space station. Just wanted to confirm which NPC Mufasa was talking about.

Comment: It's like in the real world. If you go to Gamestop, they won't give you £69.99 for your copy of Starfield. They'll give you something like £15. Then they'll sell it as second hand for £35. Stores have to make a profit!